# IEnumerable PLINQ yield

Tags: c#, ienumerable, plinq

I have a function which returns IEnumerable which iterates objects in Inbox through MAPI, but its relatively slow, so i'm going to create a pool of connections and use them in multi-threaded fashion. Is it possible to use PLINQ in the thousands of unexpensive threads ?

Comment: You're basically shooting yourself in the foot as soon as you have more threads than available cores, no matter how "inexpensive" they are. Besides, I'm not sure Windows will let a single process create thousands of threads.

Comment: Hmm, u r not right, say WMI is slow enough too, and i had successfully using it in multi-threaded fashion on only one core, and speedup was very valuable ~ 1000% with 10 threads

Comment: @zneak, you would be right if it was a CPU-bound computation. But with something that is IO-bound (like retrieving emails from a server), then using more threads than cores makes sense. Although using asynchronous IO might be even better, which doesn't waste threads.

Comment: @svick, yes, I didn't see it that way. Have this +1 for the insight.

Answer (score 2):

If, by “through MAPI”, you’re referring to the Outlook Object Model (as available in VSTO), then don’t use threading (whether through PLINQ or explicitly). The Outlook Object Model marshals all invocations back onto the main thread, making the process slower than if you were to run them directly from the main thread itself.

From [Selecting an API or Technology for Developing Outlook Solutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg608200.aspx):

> All calls to the Outlook object model and PIA execute on Outlook’s main foreground thread. The only threading model that the Outlook object model supports is single-threaded apartment (STA). Calling the Outlook object model or PIA from a background thread is not supported and can lead to errors and unexpected results in your solution.

If you want to multi-thread access to MAPI using managed code, your best bet is the [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm) library (commercial third-party solution).

Comment: I have to use own (our company COM), which access MAPI, and written in C++, and as understand is using CDO...

Comment: I don’t think CDO supports threading either (but I’m not sure). I didn’t research much into it since it’s being slowly deprecated.

Comment: Hmm, i dont think it supports multi-threading, our COM doesn't surely, but i can create many instances of the connector to Exchange.

Comment: Ah, so you’re reading from Exchange, not from Outlook? I can’t really help you in that case.

Comment: Actually i need to implement yield in multi-threaded fashion, which access through a pool of Connectors to Exchange. btw, for MAPI  outlook or exchange is not different

Answer (score 0):

This is an idea of a PLINQ solution for your task:

```
public IEnumerable<IMessage> GetMessagesParallel(IEnumerable<IConnection> connections)
{
    return connections
        .AsParallel()
        .WithDegreeOfParallelism(10)
        .SelectMany(connection => GetMessages(connection));
}
```

This method accepts a number of ready to use connections. 10 threads will be started pulling messages from each connection paralelly. `GetMessages` is the method which actually pulls messages.

Comment: Yes, i found it too IEnumerable.WithDegreeOfParallelism, but in doc there is default value of Math.Min(ProcessorCount, MAX_SUPPORTED_DOP)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(%22SYSTEM.LINQ.PARALLELENUMERABLE.WITHDEGREEOFPARALLELISM%60%601%22);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22);k(DevLang-CSHARP)&rd=true so and i ask the question will the .NET limit threads to available cores or not ?

Comment: @OlegSkripnyak - Using WithDegreeOfParallelism you can start more threads then the number of your processor cores, which is just the default value. Of course there is some upper limit, but it is much higher then the default value.

Comment: Thanks alot ! Will try to implement something wise